# how to detect change in a select tag by class

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

i am using google translate but i need to detect if there is a change in the  tag but the select only uses a class, it has no id, then i tried this code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-combo').onchange = "run_my_function()";
```

but this doesn't work please what can i do about this

Answer (score 1):

If the class is unique you could try using.
`document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-combo')[0].onchange = "run_my_function()";`

Since getElementsByClassName can return multiple elements you have to specify the exact element you want to add the onchange event on.

Comment: Yeah - what @bartb56 said, +: iterate over all elements with that class in the HTMLCollection (array-like, not an array) and set the `onchange`.  Also, if it's only one and always will be one, use `id`...

Comment: @bartb56 the console is now telling me document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: Please make sure that you have no typo in your class name or tyu using this: .document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-combo')[0].onchange = "run_my_function()"
}, false); @user13782016